# i wanted to assign a multiple conditions under a field based on some criteria like it will check if,elseif,else conditions and return true or false

Tags: asp.net-core

Question:

I have the following code:

```
IsOutOfStock = (color.quantityAvailable.value < product.OrderMinimumQuantity && color.isBuyToOrder == false || true && color.isManufactured == true || false && color.replenishmentLeadTime != null ) ? false : true,
```

Can someone please explain what this code does and how it works?

Also, I am trying to check for conditions to show colors from my MongoDB collection in asp.net mvc core. I want to implement if-else-if conditions based on certain fields. For example, if I have a quantity less than the available quantity and isBuyOrder is false and isManufactured is true, the color should be enabled. The second condition is that if the quantity is greater than the available quantity, the color should be enabled. I am using `true:false` to enable/disable colors and I am not sure how to implement this in asp.net mvc. Can someone please help?

Comment: `Can someone please explain what this code does and how it works?, `Why you need others to explain your code...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
I would recommend breaking this up into multiple lines to make it more readable. That should make it easier to understand. As for any further integration, we would need more context and details.